# ubuntu server 14.04 LTS unusual outgoing traffic

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04, traffic, htop, tomcat8

I have virtual private host with `ubuntu server 14.04 LTS`. On this server, we serve web service. We run `apache2` and `tomcat` as web server.
`apache2` + `django1.8` and `tomcat8` recently, I observed the server uses 800G out-going traffic per day, but this server is not operational and has no requests.

1. How can I analyse this problem using simple methods and how can I trace packets?
2. Using htop, there is a process `123.lock`. This process uses 100% cpu. I killed this process but after a few minuets it restarted. What should I do?
   [Relevant Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr1Yr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command `pstree` to see which process started `123.lock`. Maybe you could reconfigure the parent process to void starting `123`.

Comment: "init" started this process.this process is so doubtful case I googling in order to find out this process , but not data found!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your server is compromised. I recommend that you hire a professional system administrator to install a server for you from scratch, and make sure proper precautions are made that no such compromise can happen again.